# java 8 deserialize base64 encoded string

Tags: java, serialization

I'm taking part in a Capture the Flag contest. A question I'm stuck on relates to deserialization of a Java object. I'm interrogating a cookie string which is base64 encoded. When I decode that, I believe it is a Java serialized object which I want to deserialize in order to alter their values and re-encode in base64.

I know nothing about java, I've tried to deserialize the base64 decoded bytes, but I think this is the wrong type.

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class decode {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      try {

         // Encode using basic encoder
         String base64encodedString = "mybase64encodedstring==";
         System.out.println("Base64 encoded string :" + base64encodedString);

         // Decode
         byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedString);

         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(base64decodedBytes);
         System.out.println("Deserialised data: \n" + in.readObject().toString());

         System.out.println("Original String: " + new String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8"));


      }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
         System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

The error I get is:

> incompatible types: byte[] cannot be converted to InputStream

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **ByteArrayInputStream** instead of **ObjectInputStream**.

So, use this:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64decodedBytes);
```

instead this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(base64decodedBytes);
```

Comment: interesting thanks. how do I then print the deserialized data?

Comment: actually i think ive found how to do that. although the output appears the same as when i base64 decode it, ie non printable ascii chars.

Comment: any road, your answer is correct to my question, so marked as such. thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Hrabosch said use ByteArrayInputStream *instead*. Actually, use ByteArrayInputStream *aswell*

Also, if the data is a bunch of bytes written by an ObjectOuputStream, then it makes no sense to construct a string from those bytes

Like so

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Decode {
   public static void main(String args[]){
      try {

         // Encode using basic encoder
         // I assume you replace this with actual data...
         String base64encodedString = "mybase64encodedstring==";
         System.out.println("Base64 encoded string :" +    base64encodedString);

         // Decode
         byte[] base64decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64encodedString);

         InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64decodedBytes);
         ObjectInputStream obin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
         Object object = obin.readObject();
         System.out.println("Deserialised data: \n" + object.toString());

         // You could also try...
         System.out.println("Object class is " + object.getClass().toString());

         // Don't do this!! The original data was not a string!
         //System.out.println("Original String: " + new     String(base64decodedBytes, "utf-8"));


      }catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException e){
         System.out.println("Error :" + e.getMessage());
   }
   }  
}
```

Comment: thats helpful thanks. Its catching an error when trying to output the data, i'll work through that to see what is going on, but i'm on the right track with your info, so thanks.